# google tv- communicate with external device

Tags: google-tv, television

Is there a way to send information regarding what is being displayed/broadcast-ed by a google tv to an external device.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an API on Google TV to determine what is being broadcast on the pass-thru video.
Its easy enough to create your own broadcast network message that would contain data about what is going on the device. Alternatively, you could create an app running on Google TV that another app on another device could contact for information.